# Coq: Unknown interpretation for negative integer expressions

Tags: coq

Coq (8.5p1) seems to have some trouble understanding a "negative" expression such as `-(x + y)`, as in the following example:

```
Require Import ZArith.
(* Open Scope Z_scope. *)
Goal (forall x:Z, x + (-x) = 0) 
 -> forall a b c:Z, a + b + c + (-(c+a)) = b.
```

For the above, I got an error (for the `-x` and `(-(c+a))`  in CoqIDE):

> Error: Unknown interpretation for notation "- _".

I am confused why this error happens. Also, if I do `Open Scope Z_scope.` as in the comments, or replace integers (`Z`) with the rationals (`Q`), the error goes away. To me, `Z` and `Q` should be the same in terms of taking negatives.

Is there a reason behind this?

Comment: Are you sure that the `(-x)` part is okay? I get the same error if I simply do `Goal (forall x:Z, x + (-x) = 0).`.

Comment: @MarkDickinson You are right. I saw CoqIDE only highlighted the second instance, and thought it was only the second part. I'll edit my question.

Comment: The odd part is that it works with the rationals. Apparently `Require Import QArith` automatically opens the `Q_scope` scope, which surprises me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Coq Reference Manual v8.5:

> **Remark**: `Open Scope` and `Close Scope` do not survive the end of sections where they occur. When defined outside of a section, they are exported to the modules that import the module where they occur.

As Mark mentioned in his comment, `Require Import QArith.` opens the `Qscope` scope (outside of a section). But the exported from `ZArith` modules either open `Z_scope` locally with `Local Open Scope Z_scope.` or use `Close Scope Z_scope.` at the end.

You can use `Print Visibility.` to check the currently available notations and opened scopes.

```
Require Import Coq.ZArith.ZArith.
Print Visibility.
(* does not show anything interesting *)
```

Another take:

```
Require Import Coq.ZArith.ZArith.
Open Scope Z_scope.    
Print Visibility.
(* ...
   Visible in scope Z_scope
   ...
   "- x" := Z.opp x    (* that's what we want! *)
*)
```

And now for the rational numbers:

```
Require Import Coq.QArith.QArith.
Print Visibility.
(* ...
   Visible in scope Q_scope
   ...
   "- x" := Qopp x
*)
```